# ASP.NET button click event not working in IE

Tags: asp.net

in my asp.net page, The asp.net button click is not getting fired in IE,But in mozilla its working fine. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem when using a non runat="server" form nested inside a runat="server" form or vice versa, like so:

> <form runat="server">
>
> .... Some code
>
> <form method="post" action="somepage.aspx">
>
> </form>
>
> .... Some more code and a button
>
> </form>

The first form seems to get closed when the inner form is closed so any buttons after the closing tag of the second form don't postback

Answer (score 0):

Javascript error specific to IE is my guess.  Do you get the "error on page" message in IE?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a security settings problem. It maybe that your settings do not allow javascript to run from sites in the "internet zone". Try adding your site to "trusted sites", then refresh the browser, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also check for malformed HTML or any additional script that might interfere or intercept the postback unreliably.